# How to set spaces between binding tags in HTML code style in InteliJ for TypeScript elements?

Tags: angular, typescript, intellij-idea, coding-style, angular2-databinding

Instead of having the default `<h1>{{typeScriptVar}}</h1>` when binding elements in Angular, I want to set it to `<h1>{{ typeScriptVar }}</h1>` when I press the format code shortcut in my InteliJ.

Can you please help me, I did some research on this but didn't find the answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try `Preferences | Editor | Code Style | TypeScript | Spaces`, `Other/Within interpolation expressions`. This option affects JSX braces as well as Angular interpolations

Comment: I have done that and disabled tslint, however when i press the shortcut for reformat code (InteliJ default is Ctrl + Alt + L, or Eclipse default is Ctrl + Shift + F) there are no empty spaces added in my interpolation expressions :(